# Gatsby/React: How to prevent this repaint that occurs when chanding background-image of a display:none element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, repaint, memoization

**EDITED**: Based on answer from @HMR I include his suggestions and provide the complete code

If I have a component such as this

```js
const wait = ...
cosnt get_new_wallpaper = ... // it changes pool_of_images_fetched

const Wallpaper = () => {
  const [background, setBackground] = useState()
  const [nextBackground, setNextBackground] = useState()
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState('first') // not changed in this example
  const [pool_of_images_fetched, setPool_of_images_fetched] = useState([])


  const setNewWallpaper = useCallback(async stillMounted => {
    const wallpaper = await get_new_wallpaper(
     pool_of_images_fetched,
     setPool_of_images_fetched
    )
    stillMounted.value && setBackground(wallpaper)

    await wait(2000)
    const wallpaper2 = await get_new_wallpaper(
     pool_of_images_fetched,
     setPool_of_images_fetched
    )
    stillMounted.value && setNextBackground(wallpaper2)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    let stillMounted = {value: true}
    const init_new_wallpaper = async () => await setNewWallpaper (stillMounted)
    init_new_wallpaper()
    return function cancel() {
      stillMounted.value = false
    }
  }, [])

  return (
   <>
    <PureFirst background={background} onClick={setNewWallpaper} />
    <PureSecond background={nextBackground} onClick={setNewWallpaper} />
   </>
  )
}

const First = styled.div`
  display: ${props => (props.visible === 'first' ? 'unset' : 'none')};
  background-image: url('${props => props.background}');
`
const Second = styled.div`
  display: ${props => (props.visible === 'second' ? 'unset' : 'none')};
  background-image: url('${props => props.background}');
`
const PureFirst = memo(First)
const PureSecond = memo(Second)
```

When `setNewWallpaper()` changes `background` I see `<First>` changing accordingly, then 2s of wait, and then when it changes `nextBackground` I also see `<Second>` changing accordingly

As you can see, `<First>` is seen (`display:unset;`) but `<Second>` is unseen (`display:none;`)

The **problem** here is that `<First>` gets repainted when `<Second>` is changed, even though `<Second>` is unseen, so what happens is a *flash* in the website after these 2 seconds

Why is this code not memoized here?

Comment: What's the difference between my code and the one suggested here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326 ? Or here https://juliangaramendy.dev/use-promise-subscription/? (where apparently isMounted is deprecated(?))
- Aren't they using primitives as well?

Comment: Yes I get what you're saying (and thanks to let me know!), but then I'd like to know, are the two links I've provided wrong? or they are not using primitives and I'm not reading well their code?

Comment: Now I see, the thing is that I don't (usually I guess) send that boolean away, it is used in the same useEffect (that's why I was asking about the example), but I see that I'm doing what you're saying in this code. The explanation is that I've tried to split the code as much as possible to try to prevent this damn repaint that I cannot get rid of, sorry, you're totally right, thanks again

Comment: I've updated the code to correct that, this should work I assume (?)

Comment: Done, thanks again for helping me here :)

Comment: I've opened an issue in gatsby here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17983 there you have an starter to reproduce the flash, I'm unsure whether this is related to Gatsby or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the question, at the end the flash was caused by having the developer tools opened and with that, the *disable cache* clicked

Without it, no repaint

Answer (score 1):

You can make first and second a pure component with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) and use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to make sure setNewWallpaper doesn't change reference between renders.

I don't know what the dependencies are of setNewWallpaper since you didn't post all of the code so I assume there are none:

```
const PureFirst = React.memo(First);
const PureSecond = React.memo(Second);
export const Wallpaper = () => {
  const [background, setBackground] = useState();
  const [nextBackground, setNextBackground] = useState();

  const setNewWallpaper = useCallback(async () => {
    setBackground(...);
    await wait(2000);
    setNextBackground(...);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PureFirst
        background={background}
        onClick={setNewWallpaper}
      />
      <PureSecond
        background={nextBackground}
        onClick={setNewWallpaper}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I've included your suggestion in the question and completed the code, still gets the repaint, not really understanding where's the mistake (?)

Comment: (just added a small portion of code perhaps relevant, `pool_of_images_fetched`, that gets updated everytime `get_new_wallpaper` is executed

Comment: Curiously, isolating the code in a codepen I don't see the flash, but embebed in Gatsby I do see the flash, and without any callBack or memo at all